What is the meaning and a solution to java.lang.NullPointerException when building an Android Library using Gradle and Maven?
I'm trying to create my own custom library for Android to streamline the developing process of FTC Robots, I've tried creating a project in IntelliJ and use MavenCentral to publish it, tried publishing it to MavenLocal and even to a GitHub page and all returns the same error. As a troubleshooting step I decided to create the library as a module inside the RobotController Android Studio project, and got the same error.
The error seems to be related to a gradle process or task "ExtDexDebugAndroidTest" and the jar generated by my publish.gradle. The error reads: "java.lang.NullPointerException".
Here is my build.gradle:
plugins {
    id 'com.android.library'
}

android {
    namespace 'org.overture.ftc.overftclib'
    compileSdk 34

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 16

        aarMetadata{
            minCompileSdk = 29
        }


        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        consumerProguardFiles "consumer-rules.pro"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }



}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.7.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.10.0'
    implementation project(':FtcRobotController')
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
}

And here is my publish.gradle:
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'

ext.licenseFile = files("$rootDir/LICENSE.txt")

def pubVersion = '0.0.1'

def outputsFolder = file("$buildDir/outputs")

def versionFile = file("$outputsFolder/version.txt")

task outputVersions() {
    description = 'Prints the version of the library to a file'
    group = 'Build'
    outputs.files(versionFile)

    doFirst {
        buildDir.mkdir()
        outputsFolder.mkdir()
    }

    doLast {
        versionFile.write pubVersion
    }
}

task libraryBuild() {}

build.dependsOn outputVersions

task copyAllOutputs(type: Copy) {
    destinationDir file("$buildDir/allOutputs")
    from versionFile
    dependsOn outputVersions
}

build.dependsOn copyAllOutputs
copyAllOutputs.dependsOn outputVersions

ext.addTaskToCopyAllOutputs = { task ->
    copyAllOutputs.dependsOn task
    copyAllOutputs.inputs.file task.archiveFile
    copyAllOutputs.from task.archiveFile
}

def artifactGroupId = 'com.overture.ftc.lib'
def baseArtifactId = 'OvertureFTCLib'

// Tasks for creating additional artifacts, like sources and Javadoc
task androidSourcesJar(type: Jar) {
    classifier = 'sources'
    from android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs
}

task androidJavadocs(type: Javadoc) {
    source = android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs
    classpath += project.files(android.getBootClasspath().join(File.pathSeparator))
}

task androidJavadocsJar(type: Jar, dependsOn: androidJavadocs) {
    classifier = 'javadoc'
    from androidJavadocs.destinationDir
}

build.dependsOn androidSourcesJar
build.dependsOn androidJavadocsJar
addTaskToCopyAllOutputs(androidSourcesJar)
addTaskToCopyAllOutputs(androidJavadocsJar)

libraryBuild.dependsOn build

def releasesRepoUrl = "$buildDir/repos/releases"

publishing {
    publications {
        androidLibrary(MavenPublication) {
            groupId = artifactGroupId
            artifactId = baseArtifactId
            version = pubVersion

            afterEvaluate {
                from components.release
            }

            artifact androidSourcesJar
            artifact androidJavadocsJar
        }
    }

    repositories {
        maven {
            url = releasesRepoUrl
        }
    }
}

task cleanReleaseRepo(type: Delete) {
    delete releasesRepoUrl
}

tasks.matching { it != cleanReleaseRepo }.all { it.dependsOn cleanReleaseRepo }


Here are screenshots of the output:
ExtDexDebugAndroidTest
java.lang.NullPointerException
Hello, I'm trying to create my own custom library for Android to streamline the developing process of FTC Robots, I've tried creating a project in IntelliJ and use MavenCentral to publish it, tried publishing it to MavenLocal and even to a GitHub page and all returns the same error. As a troubleshooting step I decided to create the library as a module inside the RobotController Android Studio project, and got the same error.
The error seems to be related to a gradle process or task "ExtDexDebugAndroidTest" and the jar generated by my publish.gradle. The error reads: "java.lang.NullPointerException".
Errors:
DebugExtDexDebugAndroidTest:
> Task :overftclib:mergeExtDexDebugAndroidTest
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke \"String.length()\" because \"<parameter1>\" is null","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\santy\\.gradle\\caches\\transforms-3\\9d823f17cc7bfaba9537b6c404b8a19f\\transformed\\appcompat-resources-1.7.0-runtime.jar"}],"tool":"D8"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke \"String.length()\" because \"<parameter1>\" is null","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\santy\\.gradle\\caches\\transforms-3\\6303bfbaba1977f71e281e2c3baabe3f\\transformed\\appcompat-1.7.0-runtime.jar"}],"tool":"D8"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"java.lang.NullPointerException","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\santy\\.gradle\\caches\\transforms-3\\6303bfbaba1977f71e281e2c3baabe3f\\transformed\\appcompat-1.7.0-runtime.jar"}],"tool":"D8"}

> Task :overftclib:mergeExtDexDebugAndroidTest FAILED

java.lang.NullPointerException:
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "String.length()" because "<parameter1>" is null


Please add error information to questions as text and not as images.

Thank you for the follow-up. I edited the original question.
